# Why is my expected string not matching the output?

Tags: java, bluej

I wrote a method (using BlueJ) that returns a user's bank account information as a single line of description:

```
public String toString()
    {
        return (acctNumber + "\t" + name + "\t" + fmt.format(balance));
    }
```

And I wrote a unit test for the method that looks like this:

```
public void testToString()
    {
        Account account1 = new Account("Aurora", 772340912, 1000.00f);
        assertEquals("Test account toString failed.", "772340912    Aurora    $1,000.00", account1.toString());
    }
```

I've looked inside the "Resources" folder in BlueJ and it says: `bluej.editor.tabsize=4`so I assume that this means a tab is equal to 4 spaces. However, even though I've used four spaces in the expected output, my unit test still fails. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, a tab isn't equal to 4 spaces, it _displays_ like 4 spaces.

Comment: `\t` doesn't mean, that it will input 4 spaces in its place. What if you want to run the code on another machine where tab = 8 spaces ?? You should not check using the space count.

Comment: Ah I see, ok. So how would I type my expected string? Would I just use the "tab" button on my keyboard?

Comment: Use `\t` in your expected string instead of the spaces: `772340912\tAurora\t$1,000.00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tab is not four spaces. `bluej.editor.tabsize=4` means that the BlueJ system is rendering the tabs as if they were four spaces.

However, no matter how they are rendered, tabs are still tabs, something completely different from a space. `'\t' == 11`, while `' ' == 32`, and `"    "` can't even be compared to an `int` since it's a `String`, not a `char`.

For the expected String, use `"\t"` instead of `"    "`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get it now. I the tabsize=4 was confusing me. :)

Comment: @Michelle I have edited my answer to include an answer to that. I don't know if the tab button works, but I do know `\t` does.

Answer (score 0):

A tab is a different ASCII character from the space character. This may likely be causing some sort of mismatch where the ASCII code for a tab is compared to 4 ASCII codes for space, which will not be equal.

So simply edit one or the other so that they match up!